# Is commenting out a #include a safe way to see if it's unneeded?

Tags: c

I like to keep my files clean, so I prefer to take out includes I don't need. Lately I've been just commenting the includes out and seeing if it compiles without warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, minus a couple very specific ones). I figure if it compiles without warnings I didn't need it.

Is this actually a safe way to check if an include is needed or can it introduce UB or other problems?   Are there any specific warnings I need to be sure are enabled to catch potential problems?

<sub>n.b. I'm actually using Objective C and clang, so anything specific to those is appreciated, but given the flexibility of Objective C I think if there's any trouble it will be a general C thing. Certainly any problems in C will affect Objective C.</sub>

Comment: Could you provide a sample program in which you commented any of included file?

Comment: I would say it is. If there are `#ifdef` blocks, be sure to check any  alternative compile scenarios. e.g. Operating system defines `#ifdef WINDOWS`

Comment: It's safe in the sense that if it compiles you should be OK, unless the header maps names around (for example, if it has `#define important_func(x, y, z) alternative_implementation(x, y, z)`).  But for most general headers, if you remove it from the source and it still compiles then either some other header includes it (so it is still in use, but just not as visible) or it isn't needed.  `-Wredundant-decls` can be useful too.

Comment: This is a little philosophical, but if this is *not* a safe way to check, then how do you know you're not already missing includes right now? :-)

Comment: No.  Say you include a.h and b.h.  On one system b.h may itself include a.h and on another it does not.  Commenting out a.h will work on one system, but not the other.  System files should be less variant but this does happen.  The best is if the spec says the primary location of a prototype, define, etc. is in a given header, I include that header when I use that function, etc.

Comment: Note that it can be not so simple. Consider `a.cpp` including `b.h` and `c.h`, and `b.h` including `c.h`. Suppose that, in fact, `a.cpp` needs `b.h` and `c.h`, but `b.h` does not need anything. Now, if you remove the "`a.cpp` includes `c.h`" part, the program still compiles, but with a logically wrong dependency chain: now `a.cpp` depends on `c.h` via `b.h`.

Comment: There are few systems where `a.cpp` is a C source file.

Comment: @chux: what you're saying is that it is not sufficient to test on one platform; you need to test the removal on all platforms where your code currently compiles.  Having said that, if there's a header needed on one platform and not on others, that could be detected/handled by the platform configuration code.

Comment: @chux Interesting point about different systems. Though in this case it's only ever going to compile for one system.

Comment: This is a *it-is-OK-but-what-if* scary thing. To reduce the scariness: 1. You can review all the headers that you like to remove (if not a massive list) to see what they actually do 2. Those headers that you can't entirely be sure, let them be there until you have thoroughly tested your code for various target environments, platforms etc. 3. Consult the author who originally wrote those files (if available, of course).

Comment: There's also the macro vs. function issue. Some features are implemented as both macros and functions.  Changing headers so that the macro is not defined, but the function remains, could have subtle effects on the operation of the program.

Comment: Including an unused header files detects collisions.  Sometimes a macro or identifier is used in code but collides with an unneeded portion of the standard library.  Example: `BUFSIZE` in `#include <stdio.h>`.  Say a .c file does not need nor includes <stdio.h>.  The .c file's companion .h file may use `BUFSIZE` and is free to define.  But this causes problems when other .c files include the .h file.  Taken to an extreme, this implies including _all_ standard headers to insure collision do not occur.  I do not recommend this, but do not have a great alternative either.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, yes.

The exception would be if two headers interact in some hidden way. Say, if you:

- include two different headers which define the same symbol differently,
- both definitions are syntactically valid and well-typed,
- but one definition is good, the other breaks your program at run-time.

Hopefully, your header files are not structured like that. It's somewhat unlikely, though not inconceivable.

I'd be more comfortable doing this if I had good (unit) tests.

Answer (score 1):

Usually just commenting out the inclusion of the header is safe, meaning: if the header is needed then there will be compiler errors when you remove it, and (usually) if the header is not needed, the code will still compile fine.

This should not be done without inspecting the header to see what it adds though, as there is the (not exactly typical) possibility that a header only provides optional #define's (or #undef's) which will alter, but not break, the way a program is compiled.

The only way to be sure is to build your code without the header (if it's able to build in the first place) and run a proper regimen of testing to ensure its behavior has not changed.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. It is easy to introduce silent changes.

Suppose `header.h` defines some macros like

```
#define WITH_FEATURE_FOO
```

The C file including `header.h` tests the macro

```
#ifdef WITH_FEATURE_FOO
     do_this();
#else
     do_that();
#endif
```

Your files compile cleanly and with all warnings enabled with or without the inclusion of `header.h`, but the result behaves differently. The only way to get a definitive answer is to analyze which identifiers a header defines/declares and see if at least one of them appears in the preprocessed C file.

One tool that does this is FlexeLint from Gimpel. I don't get paid for saying this, even though they should :-) If you want to avoid shelling out big bucks, an approach I have been taking is compiling a C file to an object file with and without the header, if both succeed check for identical object files. If they are the same you don't need the header
(but watch our for include directives wrapped in `#ifdef`s that are enabled by a `-DWITH_FEATURE_FOO` option).

Answer (score 1):

No. Apart from the reasons already mentioned in other answers, it's possible that the header is needed and another header includes it indirectly. If you remove the `#include`, you won't see an error but there may be errors on other platforms.